# How compiler works with arrays?

Tags: c

I am writing a code to find the factor of the user given number. And then I want to store all the factors in an array. I created two functions, `factors` and `insert_element`. `factors` will find the factor and `insert_element` will store the factor in array as loop continues. When i call `insert_element` function form `factors` it shows me an error like `warning: passing argument 1 of ‘insert_element’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]`. I have no idea what this means and how it occurred as I am new at C language. I would like to know how a bit about how  compiler works with array along with how this error occurred

I am extremely SORRY if the question title and the question body seems to be misleading..

Here's my code below:

```
// PROGRAME TO FIND FACTORS OF GIVEN NUMBER"

#include <stdio.h>


void insert_element(int *factor_array[], int *base_divisor, int *index_of_array_elements)
//I heve used * because i want to ruturn more then one thing
{
    
    *factor_array[*index_of_array_elements] = *base_divisor;
    *index_of_array_elements++;
    
    
}
void factors(int number)
// I dont know if I want to return something or not so i kept it of type void
{
    int base_divisor = 2, factor_array[50], index_of_array_elements = 0;
    // base_divisor starts dividing given number from 2
    while (number != 1)
    {
        if (number % base_divisor==0)   //If remainder is zero then only devide number by base_divisor
        {
            number = number / base_divisor;
        }
        else        //If remainder is not zero then base_divisor will be increase by 1.
        {
            base_divisor++;
        }

        // calling the function to insert element in array
        insert_element(&factor_array[50], &base_divisor, &index_of_array_elements);
    }
    
    //i dont know why i did this but error is not caused by this.
    printf("%ls", factor_array);
}

int main()
{
    int number;
    printf("\nPROGRAME TO FIND FACTORS OF GIVEN NUMBER\n\n");
    printf("Enter the number to find factor: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    factors(number);

    
}
```

Comment: `&factor_array[50]` is a `int*` (and also out of bounds). Perhaps you meant to pass `&factor_array`?

Comment: `factor_array[50]` in a declaration, means an array of 50 things; in an expression, it means the thing at index 50 of that array.

Comment: I get this error with &factor_array

insert_element(&factor_array, &base_divisor, &index_of_array_elements);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                        |
      |                        int (*)[50]

Comment: Also change `*index_of_array_elements++` to `(*index_of_array_elements)++`.

Comment: Declare `int factor_array[]` in `insert_element` and simply pass `factor_array` when calling `insert_element`. Then use `factor_array[*index_of_array_elements] = xyz;`

Comment: If you want to return an array of two things, consider using an array of struct defined with two members:  `typedef struct {int factors[2]; int input;}factors_s;  factors_s *factors;`

Comment: ...or like the one shown in an adaptation of your code below.

Answer (score 0):

As written, the code in your post is outputting values that are not always factors. Only during the final iteration of the loop is the value for factor_array (if stored correctly) a quotient *and* a factor, which of course should also mean it is prime.

The following example, for simplification removes one function, and modifies the prototype of the remaining function to take a struct array argument.  The struct itself contains values for quotient, factor, base.  The code is also commented to explain some of the modification.  In particular I hope this will help you to understand how to pass an array as a function argument, and how to use a loop to output the values in an array.

```
typedef struct {
    long long factor;
    long long quotient;
    long long base;
}elements_s;
elements_s factor_array[50] = {{0}};

//REMOVED as all the work done here is moved to it's calling function
//    void insert_element(size_t arr_size int *factor_array[], int *base_divisor, int *index_of_array_elements)
////I heve used * because i want to ruturn more then one thing
//{
//    
//    *factor_array[*index_of_array_elements] = *base_divisor;
//    *index_of_array_elements++;
//    
//    
//}

void factors(long long number, size_t size, elements_s arr[size])//changed to pass container for results.
// I dont know if I want to return something or not so i kept it of type void
{
    long long base_divisor = 2, /**factor_array[50],*/ index_of_array_elements = 0;//factor_array replaced by struct array
    arr[index_of_array_elements].factor = 1;//fill array here, no need to send via function
    arr[index_of_array_elements].quotient = number;
    arr[index_of_array_elements].base = base_divisor; 
    int i=0;
    // base_divisor starts dividing given number from 2
    while (number != 1  && base_divisor < LLONG_MAX )
    {

        if (number % base_divisor==0)   //If remainder is zero then only devide number by base_divisor
        {
            index_of_array_elements++;//index array index
            number = number / base_divisor;
            arr[index_of_array_elements].factor = base_divisor;//fill array here, no need to send via function
            arr[index_of_array_elements].quotient = number;//fill array here, no need to send via function
            arr[index_of_array_elements].base = base_divisor;//fill array here, no need to send via function                
        }
        else        //If remainder is not zero then base_divisor will be increase by 1.
        {
            base_divisor++;
        }

        //REMOVED for simplification of example  (Not needed)
        // calling the function to insert element in array
        //insert_element(&factor_array[50], &base_divisor, &index_of_array_elements);
        //insert_element(&factor_array, &base_divisor, &index_of_array_elements);     
    }
    
    //i dont know why i did this but error is not caused by this.
    for(i = 0;i < index_of_array_elements-1; i++)//putting into loop so all populated element of array are output
    {   
        printf("quotient:%lld\nfactor:%lld\n", factor_array[i].quotient,factor_array[i].factor);//using %d for int
    }
    printf("base divisor:%lld\nfactor and quotient:%lld\nfactor:%lld\n", factor_array[i].base, factor_array[i].quotient,factor_array[i].factor);//using %d for int
}

int main(void)//this is a minumum signature for main.  Anything less is not portable.
{
    long long number = 0;  //allows larger values up to 9223372036854775807 (LLONG_MAX)
    //int factor_array[50] = {0};
    size_t size = sizeof factor_array/sizeof *factor_array;
        

    printf("\nPROGRAME TO FIND [prime] FACTORS OF GIVEN NUMBER\n\n");
    printf("Enter the number to find factor...\n");
    
    scanf("%lld", &number);//format specifier changed to accomodate larger type

    factors(number, size, factor_array);//factor_array contains all the results here, 
                                        // so prinf could be used here if index were 
                                        // also passed as argument
    
    return 0;//int main(void) requires this statement
}
```

Example run for value: `1234567890`: (multiply all *factors* to test for input)

[image]